# OAuth using login.microsoft.com returns inconsistent tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office-js, office-js-helpers

I'm using [`office-js-helpers` Authentication library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers#authentication). Using the `Microsft Azure AD 2.0 Converged auth` endpoint, I have tested logins from both a AD user (belonging to an AD tenant) and a `...@gmail.com` account registered with Microsoft.

They both return a similar payload, with an `access_token` property. The major difference is that for the AD user the `access_token` is a signed JWT, whereas for the non AD account the access token is a base64 encoded (and possibly encrypted/encoded) string.

I can use either token for other Microsoft APIs like the Graph API, so I'm not pointing out an error. However I was hoping to use the `access_token` as a JWT for my own API.

#### Is there any way to force the converged auth service to return a JWT for all logins?

Has anyone dealt with this and come up with a sensible workaround?

Comment: I'm afraid not. You can get a JWT ID Token but obviously, this won't help with securing a downstream API. Have you looked at the [On-Behalf flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of)?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur, I've looked at the massive article you're referencing. Can't figure out if implementing an On-behalf flow would result in a JWT for a MSA authentication response?

Comment: Also, @MarcLaFleur, what do you mean by a JWT ID Token? How would I get one?

Comment: It won't provide a JWT access token for an MSA, it simply doesn't support JWT tokens. The ID Token is returned if you request OpenID scopes. To do this, set your `response_type` to `id_token+code` (as opposed to just `code`) and add `openid`, `profile`, and `email` to the scopes you're requesting. This will return a JWT ID Token for both AAD and MSA accounts

Comment: Sounds interesting. Post it as an answer so I can mark it, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MSA accounts don't return a JWT based `access_token`, you can request a JWT based [`id_token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#id-tokens) using [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc).

The simplest way to think of the OpenID flow is as a variation on the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code grant. It uses the same general model with a few additional parameters.

When making the initial provider call:

1. Add `id_token` to your `response_type` query parameter.
2. Add `openid`, `email`, and `profile` to the `scope` query parameter

The final  result should look something like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={ID}&response_type=id_token+code&
redirect_uri={URI}&scope=openid+email+profile+offline_access+user.read
```

You then complete the same workflow you're using today with the Authorization Code grant. The final step, however, will now include an additional `id_token` property in the JSON payload:

```json
{
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
    "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4...",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyZDRkMTFhMi1mODE0LTQ2YTctOD...",
}
```

This `id_token` will also be a JWT based token and can be easily decoded just like you're doing with the JWT `access_token` you're getting back from AAD.